# Round to nearest n months

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing an extension function for the `DateTime` struct which rounds it to the nearest month for a given granularity, *non inclusive*. For instance:

```
Date = 11/26/18
Date.RoundMonth( 1 ); // 11/1/18 ( Rounds current month )
Date.RoundMonth( 2 ); // 11/1/18 ( Skips months 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-10 )
Date.RoundMonth( 3 ); // 10/1/18 ( Skips months 1-3, 4-6, 7-9 )
Date.RoundMonth( 4 ); // 09/1/18 ( Skips months 1-4, 5-8 )
Date.RoundMonth( 6 ); // 07/1/18 ( Skips months 1-6 )

Date = 05/11/18
Date.RoundMonth( 1 ); // 05/1/18 ( Rounds current month )
Date.RoundMonth( 2 ); // 05/1/18 ( Skips months 1-2, 3-4 )
Date.RoundMonth( 3 ); // 04/1/18 ( Skips months 1-3 )
Date.RoundMonth( 4 ); // 05/1/18 ( Skips months 1-4 )
Date.RoundMonth( 6 ); // 01/1/18 ( 5 is within 1-6 )
```

Here's my current implementation

```
public static DateTime RoundMonth( this DateTime date, int roundValue )
{
  var monthIndex = date.Month / roundValue * roundValue;
  return new DateTime( date.Year, monthIndex, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc );
}
```

There are multiple issues with this implementation.

- If `date.Month` is less than `roundValue`, `monthIndex` is always zero, and the `DateTime` constructor does not allow for a 0 month index. If `monthIndex` is greater than zero, it includes the last month of the prior period (whereas my above example does not).
- If 1 is added to the end of the `monthIndex` it works, but the month is 12, then the `DateTime` constructor throws an exception because the calculated month is 13. If monthIndex is 1, it improperly increments to 2.

I can't think of a way to fix these problems without a nasty chunk of arithmetic, if statements, and calls to `Math.Min`. I must be missing something obvious...

It is worth mentioning that **this function will be called a lot** (it is being used to sort dates into buckets), so performance is somewhat of a concern.

Comment: You're very close. Subtract `1` before doing the math, then add it back at the end. `Math.Floor( (date.Month-1)/roundValue ) * roundValue + 1`